# Logic simulator c++ with list implementation

Tags: c++, list, simulator

I am working on a logic simulator in C++. It is a project of an computer engineering course. This simulator receives two input files, the circuit description and input patterns. The circuit description include the number of input and output and the gates; for example:
AND2 I1, I2, N1 //is a AND-Gate with two input and a node N1 as output.
I think to implement it with structure or list, but I don't know how to connect all nodes and how to write a function that evaluates the output(or outputs).

Comment: Graph theory seems like a good subject to read up on.

Comment: show us what you have done till now

Comment: @JoachimPileborg We have done only list in theory so I don't think that in this project I can use Graph theory.

Comment: @VinayShukla I don't write code yet because first I want to understand how to do that

Comment: @user46 In that case, this question is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could model the gates as classes which have inputs and produce an output. For example:

```
class Gate
{
public:
    virtual ~Gate() {}
    virtual bool read() = 0;
};

class AndGate : public Gate
{
private:
    Gate *m_Input1;
    Gate *m_Input2;

public:
    AndGate(Gate *input1, Gate *input2) : m_Input1(input1), m_Input2(input2)
    {
    }

    bool read() override
    {
        return m_Input1->read() & m_Input2->read();
    }
};

class OrGate : public Gate
{
private:
    Gate *m_Input1;
    Gate *m_Input2;

public:
    OrGate(Gate *input1, Gate *input2) : m_Input1(input1), m_Input2(input2)
    {
    }

    bool read() override
    {
        return m_Input1->read() | m_Input2->read();
    }
};


class NotGate : public Gate
{
private:
    Gate *m_Input;

public:
    NotGate(Gate *input) : m_Input(input)
    {
    }

    bool read() override
    {
        return !m_Input->read();
    }
};

class ConstantLine : public Gate
{
private:
    bool m_State;

public:
    ConstantLine(bool state) : m_State(state)
    {
    }

    bool read() override
    {
        return m_State;
    }
};
```

This basically gives you a graph network. You can now plug the gates together. For example to compute `((X | Y) & !Z)` you would do:

```
ConstantLine x(true);
ConstantLine y(false);
ConstantLine z(true);

NotGate notGate(&z);
OrGate orGate(&x, &y);
AndGate andGate(&orGate, &notGate);

bool result = andGate.read();
```

In your solution you'll be dynamically creating the gates, so instead of using raw pointers you should use a smart pointer, such as `std::shared_pointer<Gate>` to manage the inputs to the gate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With this solution I can create a model of the circuit and after read the file of input and load the value? Because the file of input may be very large and so I can't use a vector of constantLine (in this case) to store them.

Comment: @user46 - a lot will depend on how the file specifies the gates. It may be that you don't need a vector or list to store the gates in as the graph of gates you assemble may be sufficient.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much

Comment: how can I implement a function(for example the constructor of AndGate class) that receives more inputs, where the number of inputs isn't known because it is written in the file?